# If a function $f$ is not defined on $[-2,0]$, what can we say about $\lim_{x\to-2}f(x)$?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, limits, functions, graphing-functions

I was thinking of a strange case in which we can say the limit is undefined. ( I mean different than *the limit does not exist*.)

So I generated the graph of a piecewise function $f(x)$. There is a discontinuity but the graph is is of the same function just in case.

$$f(x)=\begin{cases} 1 & -5<x<-4 \\x^2 & x>0 \end{cases}$$

[image: Graph]

Off course the limit does not looks to exist( or perhaps it does).

Why it is so?

See below!

$$\lim_{x \to \ -2^-} f(x)= \text{the limit does not exist}$$

Why did I say that?

Because I think that as we are moving closer to -2 from left , the value of $f(x)$ seems to approach undefined.

And if I were to create a table also. I reach this conclusion but it doesn't makes sense because I cannot say the if there is a x in the range of $\epsilon$ of *undefined* we can find a $\delta$ and the formal limit definition. So according this it brings me to the conclusion the limit does not exist.

But the problem with my this conclusion is that, I never imagined that an one sided limit cannot exist.

> So I doubt if I am correct. If not why?

Now,

$$\lim_{x \to \ -2^+} f(x)= \text{the limit does not exist}$$

And the reason is same again.

Now I ask myself:-
$$\lim_{x \to \ -2} f(x)= ?$$

Off course the limit does not exist but we see the left and right limit , both were equal right so shouldn't exist?

Or

We cannot say they were equal because the answers were not numbers so we cannot compare and say they are equal and and hence the limit does not exist.

Which one is correct?

Comment: The function is continuous in the domain . You only talk about limit in the domain of function. Otherwise it does not make sense.

Comment: So like you say the limit at -2 does not exist. That is wrong. The function is not even defnied in a neighborhood of -2. You cannot conclude anything about something which is not defined. When you say $\lim_{x\to 0^{+}}\ln(x)=-\infty$. You use the fact that log is defined for $x>0$. And you specifically say the limit is $-\infty$. And not "does not exist". There is a difference between infinite limits and limit which does not exist.

Comment: The key point here is that the concept of a limit at a point is only defined if the function is defined in some neighbourhood of that point or, at least, the point is an accumulation point of the domain of the function (these are 2 ways to define it, some authors prefer the former, others the later)

Comment: @Mr.GandalfSauron Can you explain it in a bit more detail, why should the limit be $-\infty$.

Comment: @StefanOctavian Yes , it makes sense because we cannot see what we are approaching if  there is nothing in the neighborhood, right?

Comment: @MohdSaad I meant that as a general example to try and explain why "limit does not exist" and "limit is infinity" or "limit is -infinity" are not the same. You see that if I define a function say f(x)=ln(x) for x in [1,10]. and I ask you what is the limit of f at 0. Then the question itself is nonsense as f has not been defined in a neibouhood of 0(or precisely a set of which 0 is an accumulation point). You will understand these notions more clearly when you take analysis. So if instead I defined f on (0,10). I can say something about the right hand limit of f at 0 and it is just -infty.

Comment: @Mr.GandalfSauron Okay, So I cannot say that the *limit doesn't exist* just because it is nonsense to talk about the limit if their are no points in the neighborhood of x in the domain of our function, right?

Comment: @MohdSaad . Yes. You define limit of a function defined on a set for points which are the accumulation points of the sets. Speaking strictly of real analysis....accumulation points are those for which the given set intersects any open set containing that point at infinitely many points. You can look up the definition if this verbal one does not suit you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The prerequisite for a limit to exit is that the function should be well defined in the neighbourhood of where we will be finding the limit.In this case the function is not defined at or near x=2 so limit does not exist.It is not that the value of () seems approaches undefined, instead the limit does not exist as the function is well defined only in its domain $(-5,-4)\cup(0,\infty)$.